# Intellij indexing entire filesystem - how to stop it?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to stop Intellij from indexing the entire filesystem and not just the project? did i screw up a setting somewhere somehow? where is it and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you know it's scanning your entire filesystem? What's the reason for you to think this?

Comment: it shows "indexing [filename]" at the bottom right, and all the files are outside of the project directory.

Comment: Is there a reference in one of your modules sources/dependencies/libs to the root of your filesystem somewhere that was not excluded?